# Wrap truncated text in Double quotes in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-text

Expected result (Truncated text wrapped in double-quotes):
["Let's figure out your preferen..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcNW7.png)

I tried using

```
Text("\"\(description)\"")
    .lineLimit(1)
```

but unable to get a double quote at the end ["Let's figure out your preferen...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVXkG.png)

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried so far and where you are struggling.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not yet @bodich

Answer (score -1):

As others have said, you should give us some ideas of what you have tried. One possible solution can be the following.

struct ContentView: View {

```
let description: String = "Let's figure out your preferences and interests for this trip and get your trip sorted with the best recommendations that work for you"



   var body: some View {
        Text("\"\(description)\"")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the screenshot how it was truncated

Answer (score -1):

You have to individually escape each character. The following code would show a double quote at the end.

```swift
Text("\" This will show double quotes at the start and end \"")
```

This is done via `escaping` - you need to put a `\` in front of each character that should be taken as a text character instead of code. Note how the code above is highlighted too - only the first and last quotes are part of the code, so only they are in a different color.